# Line wrapping in GtkCheckButton or GtkRadioButton labels

Tags: c, checkbox, gtk, radio-button, word-wrap

Is there any way to get the label of a `GtkCheckButton` or `GtkRadioButton` to wrap when its parent container is resized small enough so the label won't fit on one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access button's child widget — it's a `GtkLabel` in default setup, — and set various properties on it, e.g. `wrap`.  However, since there is no height-for-width layout negotiation in GTK+ 2.x, what you want exactly can be difficult / close to impossible to achieve.  Note that you can also replace the button's child if you want.

Comment: I'd forgotten it was also a `GtkContainer`! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also got that working this way (using GtkSharp)

```
RadioButton rb;

/* Initialize the radio button ... */

//Set its wrap mode
(rb.Child as Gtk.Label).Wrap = true;
(rb.Child as Gtk.Label).LineWrap = true;
(rb.Child as Gtk.Label).LineWrapMode = Pango.WrapMode.Word;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question properly, wrapping the label of a `GtkCheckButton` is quite straightforward, at least on GTK3:

```
/* gcc -o wrap wrap.c $(pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-3.0) */
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void
on_activate(GtkApplication *app)
{
    GtkWidget *button;
    GtkWidget *label;
    GtkWidget *window;

    button = gtk_check_button_new_with_label("Some really useful text goes here");
    label  = gtk_bin_get_child(GTK_BIN(button));
    gtk_label_set_line_wrap(GTK_LABEL(label), TRUE);
    gtk_label_set_max_width_chars(GTK_LABEL(label), 0);

    window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 600, 480);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), button);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;

    app = gtk_application_new("org.gnome.LabelWrapping", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(on_activate), NULL);
    status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref(app);

    return status;
}
```