# gtk: label which goes multi-line instead of expanding horizontally

Tags: python, user-interface, pygtk, gtk

I have a `VBox` which looks like this:

```
ImportantWidget
  HSeparator
    Label
```

I want this window to be only as wide as `ImportantWidget` needs to be, and no wider. However, the `Label` can sometimes grow to be very long. I want the following logic: if `Label` can fit all its text without expanding the `VBox` horizontally (after it has grown enough to fit `ImportantWidget`), then its text should all be on one line. But if it would overflow and cause horizontal resizing, then it should instead split its text across multiple lines.

Is there a widget that does this already, that's better than `Label` for the task? If not, what should I use?

Comment: More or less a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152515/line-wrapping-in-gtkcheckbutton-or-gtkradiobutton-labels ; the answer especially also applies to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want a dynamically resizing label, which GTK doesn't do out of the box. There's a Python port of VMWare's WrapLabel widget in the [Meld repository](http://git.gnome.org/cgit/meld/tree/meld/ui/wraplabel.py). (From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893748/pygtk-dynamic-label-wrapping).)

Answer (score 1):

Ah yes [this](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/ch-MiscellaneousWidgets.html) shows how to do it:

```
l = gtk.Label("Painfully long text" * 30)
l.set_line_wrap(True)
```

Comment: this still doesn't work fully, though. it seems like when the width allocated to the label expands, the line-wrapping does not change, but stays the same. anyone have a better answer? even when setting `set_justify` to `JUSTIFY_FILL`, that problem arises.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

example of a dynamic label who works in multi-line according to the size of the window and text:

```
import gtk

class DynamicLabel(gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        gtk.Window.__init__(self)

        self.set_title("Dynamic Label")
        self.set_size_request(1, 1)
        self.set_default_size(300,300) 
        self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)

        l = gtk.Label("Painfully long text " * 30)
        l.set_line_wrap(True)
        l.connect("size-allocate", self.size_request)
        ImportantWidget  = gtk.Label("ImportantWidget")

        vbox = gtk.VBox(False, 2)
        HSeparator = gtk.HSeparator()
        vbox.pack_start(ImportantWidget, False, False, 0)
        vbox.pack_start(HSeparator, False, False, 0)
        vbox.pack_start(l, False, False, 0)


        self.add(vbox)
        self.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
        self.show_all()

    def size_request(self, l, s ):
        l.set_size_request(s.width -1, -1)

DynamicLabel()
gtk.main()
```